# Else block in Python code keeps throwing invalid syntax error...no matter what I do to correct it

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7, if-statement, statements

I am not an expert Pythonista per se so I will begin with that as a clarification for me asking what could be a considered a trivial question about an else statement issue I have. Anyway for the sake of brevity, I went through all of the else syntax questions on stackoverflow regarding the same/similar issues and I was still unable to resolve the problem.  Here is the code block in question:

```
   else: 
        m_len -= 33 
        dst.append(32) 
        n, m_len = divmod(m_len, 255) 
        dst.extend("\x00" * n) 
        dst.append(m_len) 
        dst.append((m_off << 2) & 0xff) 
        dst.append((m_off >> 6) & 0xff)
   else: #This is the line being complained about
        m_off -= 0x4000 
   if m_len <= 9: 
        dst.append(0xff & (16 | ((m_off >> 11) & 8) | (m_len - 2)))
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advise that can be offered! Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have more than one [`else` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) in a single conditional block
Change the first `else` to `elif` and specify some condition

Answer (score 1):

You conditions must be like that:

```
if (condition):#the program can choose as many "if" as many you put in your program (in theory)
 ..code..
#here you can add as many "if" as you want
elif (condition):#the program will only choose one block you must have a "if" block before
 ..code..
#here again you can add as many "elif" as you want
else:#before "else" you must have a if block before
 ..code..
#here only one "else"
```

how do you think the program could choose else or else?! lol